# Hiding setText value of a JButton

Tags: java, swing, hide, jbutton

I am coding an image puzzle game and one part of the code is to compare the pieces the user has selected to the pieces of the correct image.

Each image piece is already added to a JButton as an ImageIcon.

An identifier is required to differentiate each image piece apart and also for comparision.

I am setting a setText() for each JButton created as the identifier.

But doing so will cause both the ImageIcon and setText to show up on the JButton.

Is there a way to hide the setText value and only display the ImageIcon ?

```
        private String id;
        private int cc;
        private JButton[] button = new JButton[9];

        cc += 1;
        id += ""+cc;

        for(int a=0; a<9; a++){
            // dd refers to the variable for the image pieces for each JButton
        button[a].setIcon(new ImageIcon( dd ));
        button[a].setText(id);
        }
```

Comment: You can use a _Map_ for storing each id for each button. So you can identify each button using this _Map_. Or you can use _setName_ for each button and for each image.

Comment: IMHO, instead of comparing `JButton`'s `images`, you can use an int `Array` having same size as that of `JButton` Array, and simply associate one number with each `ImageIcon`, hence you can compare this array values to get your desired result. Or instead of using `setText()` you can use [setName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName(java.lang.String)), as an alternative for this approach.

Comment: 2 interesting ways to do it, `Map` and `setName()` . Will read up on them :)

Comment: Sorry for bringing up an old thread, but I do have issues obtaining the appropriate setName() for the buttons in the array which the user is supposed to drag the pieces to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453513/comparing-components-via-setname  Any further aid is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend making another array of `String`s:

```
String[] ids = new String[button.length];
```

And then `button[a]`'s ID would be `ids[a]`.

Here is your code with the change:

```
    private String id;
    private int cc;
    private JButton[] button = new JButton[9];
    private String[] ids = new String[button.length];

    //cc += 1;
    //id += ""+cc;
    id += Integer.toString(++cc); //easier way

    for(int a=0; a<9; a++){
        // dd refers to the variable for the image pieces for each JButton
        button[a].setIcon(new ImageIcon( dd ));
        ids[a] = id;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I got that too, that's why the comment from me is gone +1 to the idea, provided by you :-) Though I still think you missed to add the thingy suggested by you in the modified code.